# subtract two rows in pyspark and append ans as new row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below pyspark dataframe

```
     stat   col_A    col_B       col_C     col_D   
    count   14       14          14 14      14
     75%    4        4001       160987      49  
     50%    3        3657       131225      38
```

I want to subtract 50% row from 75% row and add new row **result** in the same dataframe like below:

```
     stat   col_A    col_B       col_C     col_D   
    count   14       14          14 14      14
     75%    4        4001       160987      49  
     50%    3        3657       131225      38  
   result   1        344        26762       11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as easy as one would have thought because of the need to operate on rows instead of columns. Try the code below where you add one more row using `union`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.union(
    df.agg(
        F.lit('result').alias('stat'), 
        *[
            (
                F.max(F.when(F.col('stat') == '75%', F.col(c))) - 
                F.max(F.when(F.col('stat') == '50%', F.col(c)))
            ).alias(c) 
            for c in df.columns[1:]
        ]
    )
)

result.show()
+------+-----+-----+------+-----+
|  stat|col_A|col_B| col_C|col_D|
+------+-----+-----+------+-----+
| count|   14|   14|  1414|   14|
|   75%|    4| 4001|160987|   49|
|   50%|    3| 3657|131225|   38|
|result|    1|  344| 29762|   11|
+------+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works for me. could you please explain how it works?

Comment: it gets the rows corresponding to 75% and 50% by aggregating over all rows and only filtering those where stat is 75% or 50%.